# Cocoapods Installation fails on MacBook Pro M1 Apple Silicon Mac

Tags: cocoapods, macos-big-sur, apple-silicon, apple-m1

I have already tried installing while running terminal on "Rossetta" mode. But even then the installation fails.

Command I used : `sudo gem install cocoapods`
Also tried installing Homebrew but I get the same error.

The error I'm getting is as below:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
dlsym(0x7fbc673521d0, Init_date_core): symbol not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: Start by installing your own ruby. Use of /Library/Ruby/ is wrong.

Comment: To some extent I could solve this issue by installing older version of the gem 'date' module. To be exact date(2.0.0) also I downgraded the 'bigdecimal' to 1.4.1

Comment: I have been struggling with this issue as well and it is preventing me from installing anything at all. e.g. 'sudo gem install date -v 2.0' (attempting your solution) gives me the same date_core error. i am running Terminal and Xcode under Rosetta but this seems to be the only thing keeping me from being able to update my Cocoapods.

Comment: Slight correction. Try exact version number date -v 2.0.0 instead of 2.0. I hope it works.

Answer (score 8):

I also had the same issue when I installed cocoapods via `sudo gem install cocoapods`. I am on a MacBook Pro with an Apple Silicon (M1) chip. To fix this, I had to uninstall cocoapods using `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` and re-install using this command:

`arch -arm64 brew install cocoapods`

Comment: Using homebrew is an easy, nice and clean fix. I think its the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution, man. When I google this question, you should get same answer that just like this:

```
$ sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

$ arch -x86_64 pod install
```

but this is wrong!!! check your error log

> /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in
> `require':
> dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle,
> 9): no suitable image found. Did find: (LoadError)
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle: mach-o,
> but wrong architecture
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle: mach-o,
> but wrong architecture -
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/date-3.1.1/lib/date_core.bundle

this means you need date for gem. so:

```
sudo gem install date
```

and it‘s done!!

you may also see this error:

```
dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.2/lib/bigdecimal.bundle, 9): no suitable image found. Did find: (LoadError)
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.2/lib/bigdecimal.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.2/lib/bigdecimal.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bigdecimal-3.0.2/lib/bigdecimal.bundle
```

so, just:

```
sudo gem install bigdecimal
```

and it‘s done!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can go to this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9907) for workarounds. Below command seems to be working for some people on M1 machine for installing Cocoapods.

> arch -x86_64 sudo gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

I struggled some hours with this problem, but I think, I found the solution:

First uninstall cocoapods
In the terminal run

**sudo gem uninstall cocoapods**

Then reinstall cocoapods using the homebrew

**brew install cocoapods**

Inside ios folder run
**pod repo update**

Go back to the root of project then run

**Flutter run**